# Save JSON to file with iOS using request to server

Tags: ios, json, asynchronous

I have a problem. This is my code

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

-(void)saveJson
{

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        kURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSDictionary *json  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Result.plist"];

    NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
    [json writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

I can get the json in the json variable, so if I put a log I will see the json, the file is created too. But when I want to watch the content of the file, this plist does not content any value, just the xml type of apple. The json is well formed and I have tested with a simple app, but in this case the dictionary is not saved in the file. This class is in one class. So in the main view controller, in the viewDidLoad method I use this

```
MarketDataAPI *marketApi = [[MarketDataAPI alloc] init];
[marketApi updateMarketApi];
```